# Issues reading/writing to NAS from IIS 6.0 and PHP

Tags: php, iis, permissions, fopen, isapi-rewrite

I am having trouble getting a script to write to an attached network drive/NAS. The strange thing is, the same webserver has no problems reading/writing to the same directory from an existing script on the server. I am not strong with Windows/IIS webserver so I will try to list as many things as I can.

First of all, I am using a simple test script to perform an is_dir and also is_writeable. I use the same $dir variable as the one from the working script.

Here is an example:

```
$aftn_path = "\\\\skynas01\\shared_files\\";
if(is_dir($aftn_path)) echo "$aftn_path is a directory."; else echo "$aftn_path is not a directory";
```

What's returned is:

> \\skynas01\shared_files\ is not a directory

I can copy/paste the directory string into a run command and the directory opens fine. I checked permissions on that directory and shows "everyone" can read/write/execute from that Dir. Again, another script with the exact same directory string with an fopen() call works with no problems and I can write files there.

The only other thing I can think of could be that the IIS server uses helicon ISAPI Rewrite module and the script which works does have a rule pointing to that PHP file (which I don't understand either)

Here is the ISAPI rewrite rule

```
  RewriteRule /sys/filing(.*)   /phpsys/filing.php [I,L]
```

To me, it looks like it's just aliasing /sys -> /phpsys.

The \skynas01 network mount is mapped to an internal drive on the server, and is not accessible by the drive letter either (G:/shared_files). I've also tried using forward slashes (//skynas01/shared_files). Does anyone have any ideas why my script can't see this directory?

Answer (score 0):

That's not ISAPI_Rewrite, definitely. you can check by removing the rule from the config file and request the thing you need. It'd still throw the error.

Comment: That would be correct. Upon further investigation, the PHP script that is able to write to the NAS is seen as a specific user, whereas my script is seen as the default IIS user (IUSR_$SERVERNAME)  so it's definitely a permission thing. I am trying to figure out how this script is changing it's identity.